# bootstrap collapse add class for open item

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used `bootstrap framework` for display collapsible panels in my webpage. By default the first panel is open. I need to `add class` to the `opened panel's head` on page load. If i click any panel the class should be removed. How to do this?

Comment: Please show some code. Also, which version of bootstrap?

Comment: can you share your relevant code?

Comment: I have downloaded the framework from this site and please refer http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse for code

Comment: Make sure you have properly link the javascript required. Make sure you have activate the collapsible using data attributes or javascript. Post your code so we can help

Comment: @lifeline any reason why you can't just add the class in the HTML of the element itself? then you would just need some js to remove the class when another link is clicked, also even though we can see the documented examples in Bootstrap's main site, it's better if you show us your implementation

Comment: Please refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ehvDd/1/ for my code.

Comment: Here's a version with the Bootstrap resources loaded externally - http://jsfiddle.net/ehvDd/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what you want. Try this

```
var panelHeadClass = 'foo',
    accordion = $('#accordion'),
    openPanel = accordion.find('.panel-collapse.collapse.in'),
    openPanelHead = openPanel.prev('.panel-heading').addClass(panelHeadClass);

accordion.on('click', '.panel', function() {
    openPanelHead.removeClass(panelHeadClass);
});
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/ehvDd/3/

Comment: one more help. How can i add the class to the active panel head on click the panel and remove the class while it is not active?